# Query Data category tree structure by SOQL statement

Tags: soql, salesforcedx, knowledge, data-category

Using SOQL statement, I want to query the Data Categories tree structure that I have created on Saleforce. How can I do this?

Comment: if you add more details about the information you have, or your code, i can give you a more meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Knowledge Article Version can have multiple DataCategories. [For reference,](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_erd_knowledge.htm) is the data model. You'll see DataCatagories as `Article__DataCategorySelection`

As to how do you get the `Article__DataCategorySelection`?  I'm not clear where you're starting from, but the query below is a place to start.  [Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relations) give you some instructions on working with Data Categories and SOQL

```
 SELECT Id, Title
  (
    SELECT Id
    FROM DataCategorySelections
  )
FROM Offer__kav WHERE publishStatus='online';
```

PS- Something I learned the hard way, you can't use triggers on Article Types, and you need to use formulas instead.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no a way to query directly with SOQL from Salesforce but you can do in apex with metadata, check these links:

For get all Categories
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_data_categories.htm

Once you have the API name with the data from above you can do filtering with this link:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_with_datacategory.htm

You can check this code to have a best understand:

```
List<DescribeDataCategoryGroupResult> describeCategoryResult;
List<Schema.DescribeDataCategoryGroupStructureResult> results;
List <DataCategoryGroupSobjectTypePair> pairs;
try {
//Creating the list of sobjects to use for the describe call
List<String> objType = new List<String>();
objType.add('KnowledgeArticleVersion');

//Describe Call
describeCategoryResult = Schema.describeDataCategoryGroups(objType);

//Using the results and retrieving the information
for(DescribeDataCategoryGroupResult singleResult : describeCategoryResult){
    //Getting the name of the category
    //System.debug('###singleResult.getName: ' + singleResult.getName());
    //Getting the name of label
    //System.debug('###singleResult.getLabel: ' + singleResult.getLabel());
    //Getting description
    //System.debug('###singleResult.getDescription: ' + singleResult.getDescription());
    //Getting the sobject
    //System.debug('###singleResult.getSobject: ' + singleResult.getSobject());
    System.debug('###' + singleResult.getLabel());
    
    results = new List<Schema.DescribeDataCategoryGroupStructureResult>();
    
    try {
        pairs = new List<DataCategoryGroupSobjectTypePair>();
        
        DataCategoryGroupSobjectTypePair pair1 = new DataCategoryGroupSobjectTypePair();
        pair1.setSobject('KnowledgeArticleVersion');
        pair1.setDataCategoryGroupName(singleResult.getName());
        
        pairs.add(pair1);
        
        results = Schema.describeDataCategoryGroupStructures(pairs, false);
        
        for (DescribeDataCategoryGroupStructureResult singleResult1 : results) {
            //Getting the name of the category
            //System.debug('######singleResult1.getName: ' + singleResult1.getName());
            //Getting the name of label
            //System.debug('######singleResult1.getLabel: ' + singleResult1.getLabel());
            //Getting description
            //System.debug('######singleResult1.getDescription: ' + singleResult1.getDescription());
            //Getting the sobject
            //System.debug('######singleResult1.getSobject: ' + singleResult1.getSobject());
            System.debug('######' + singleResult1.getLabel());
            
            for (Schema.DataCategory singleResultSubTopCatLevel1 : singleResult1.getTopCategories() ) {
                //Getting the name of the category
                //System.debug('#########singleResultSubTopCatLevel1.getName: ' + singleResultSubTopCatLevel1.getName());
                //Getting the name of label
                //System.debug('#########singleResultSubTopCatLevel1.getLabel: ' + singleResultSubTopCatLevel1.getLabel());
                System.debug('#########' + singleResultSubTopCatLevel1.getLabel());
                
                for (Schema.DataCategory singleResultSubChildCatLevel2 : singleResultSubTopCatLevel1.getChildCategories() ) {
                    //Getting the name of the category
                    //System.debug('############singleResultSubChildCatLevel2.getName: ' + singleResultSubChildCatLevel2.getName());
                    //Getting the name of label
                    //System.debug('############singleResultSubChildCatLevel2.getLabel: ' + singleResultSubChildCatLevel2.getLabel());
                    System.debug('############' + singleResultSubChildCatLevel2.getLabel());
                    
                    for (Schema.DataCategory singleResultSubTopCatLevel3 : singleResultSubChildCatLevel2.childcategories ) {
                        //Getting the name of the category
                        //System.debug('###############singleResultSubTopCatLevel3.getName: ' + singleResultSubTopCatLevel3.getName());
                        //Getting the name of label
                        //System.debug('###############singleResultSubTopCatLevel3.getLabel: ' + singleResultSubTopCatLevel3.getLabel());
                        System.debug('###############' + singleResultSubTopCatLevel3.getLabel());
                        
                        for (Schema.DataCategory singleResultSubChildCatLevel4 : singleResultSubTopCatLevel3.childcategories ) {
                            //Getting the name of the category
                            //System.debug('##################singleResultSubChildCatLevel4.getName: ' + singleResultSubChildCatLevel4.getName());
                            //Getting the name of label
                            //System.debug('##################singleResultSubChildCatLevel4.getLabel: ' + singleResultSubChildCatLevel4.getLabel());
                            System.debug('##################' + singleResultSubChildCatLevel4.getLabel());
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    } catch(Exception e){
        System.debug(e.getMessage());
    }
    
    
}
} catch(Exception e){
    System.debug(e.getMessage());
}
```